# How to submit multi-checkbox items in a formatted string to SharePoint lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, lookup-column

I'm new to InfoPath and SharePoint and i also use the trial version of qRules, i have 2 sharepoint lists, with one (let's call it "list1") having a lookup column to the second ("list2"), and this column permit multi-items selection. 
when i am using the default form i can add an item to "list1" with all the selected items in the lookup column separated with a semicolon. but when want to use a custom form, and a multi-checkbox, and i don't know how the selected items ID's must be submitted to the SharePoint list (i tried separating the items ID's with : ',' , ';' , '.' ; ' ' ...).

I want the selected items to be displayed like this in the lookup column :
[image]

Thank's for your help.

Comment: are you using qRules with the SubmitToSharePointList command?

Comment: Tried building a string that conforms to the `SPFieldLookupValueCollection` format using the IDs and lookup value strings? I haven't worked with InfoPath much but with managed code you can set a multi-value lookup field using a string that is specially formatted for use with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms429163(v=office.15).aspx) overload. So instead of setting the column value using a string containing the IDs and random delimiters, try building a string like "1;#Android;#2;#Language Java;#3;#MySql..." and setting that string as the lookup colum's value.

Comment: @teylyn yes i am

Comment: @nsturdivant i used qRules because i'm new with C# and i don't have enough time to accomplish this project. i already tried this delimiter but i an error in the command field of qRules

Comment: @THEDJA, Qdabra have very good support. If the issue is related to qRules you should approach them directly on Infopathdev.com

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use SPD workflow for this.  You can make a workflow that breaks them up like that into a different column.  For multiple check boxes when updating a list item in SPD, it offers it as a string or a comma separated values.  Just an idea.

Comment: but i need them to redirect to the source list

Comment: Is the purpose of the second list just to hold the selected items?

Comment: Yes, and to show further informations on selected items, on clicking on them